# How to find if large list of keywords is in Django TextField

Tags: python, django

Say I have the following models:

```
class NamedEntity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    NE_CHOICES = (
        ('PER', 'Person'),
        ('TTL', 'Title / Role'),
        ('ORG', 'Organization'),
        ('LOC', 'Location')
    )
    ne_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=NE_CHOICES)

class Document(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    entities = models.ManyToManyField(NamedEntity)

    def find_entities(self):
        ## First locate user entities
        ## Locate general Named Entities
        print "Finding entities..."
```

And let's say there are about a thousand or so named entities in the database. What would be the best way to index/search the content field of the document, to find all possible instances of the entire list of named entities as a method of the Document model?

Example data:

A Document.content field might contain the following string:

```
"Hey Joe,

I wanted to see if you and Cassy might be interested in going to Franky's on friday night.

-Fred"
```

The full table of NamedEntities would contain .name field entries such as the following:

```
"Mark"
"Peter"
"Franky's"
"Seattle"
"Fred"
"Amber"
"Joe"
...assuming a couple thousand entries.
```

I want to find all possible instances of those NamedEntity.name values within the Document.content field. In terms of how I want the result to look, I would be okay with either a tagged version of the original string:

```
"Hey \(NE/01254)Joe,

I wanted to see if you and \(NE/01942)Cassy might be interested in going to \(NE/02223)Franky's on friday night.

-\(NE/023432)Fred"
```

or a dictionary of string indexes:

```
{ 01254 : (4,6),
  01942 : (33, 37),
  02223 : ... }
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a simple dataset, and an example of what you would expect as the result after you make your index/search?

Comment: @solartic Updated with example data. Very open to suggestions and even taking a different approach entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, my thoughts are as followed:

> - Get data from the content field
> - Split the data into the different words which should give you and array
>     of words.
> - Either group similar words - a dictionary can be used: {'mary': 5,
>     'mark': count}
> - Or remove duplicate words using python's list data structure
> - You can possibly remove words you are sure are not a valid names
> - Search to see if any of the words are in the database

I'm assume you've considered indexing the NamedEntity.name field.

If the list of words is small an or statement seem like the best idea for searching for the names in the database. However, I'm not sure how well large are statements perform. Moreover I have no idea of how large that content field could be.

If the TextField has more unique words than the database this probably would not bee the best method.

Hopefully my understanding was correct.

Comment: I believe an indexing solution is probably what I'm looking for. Your answer would work fine if the list of related words was small enough, or the number of Content objects were small enough, but I imagine both of these numbers being large.

Comment: Just made a comment on my previous post and notices you comments. You are correct my method is not much use if both datasets are large. This is an interesting problem, and one that I'm curious about as well. So I'll keep pondering.

Comment: If I come to a solution I will come back and post it. In the meantime I have mitigated (read: avoided) the problem by ignoring the eventual scaling issues and taking advantage of a feature in the [new beta Python regex model](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)

`option_set = set(["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"])
regex.compile(r"\L<options>", options=option_set)`

The new regex module allows for the creation of named lists. So I pull all the NamedEntity.name values into a set using a queryset and then place that set into the regex.

Comment: This seem interesting I'll have to take a closer look when I have some more time. Thanks for the feedback.